# C++ implementation of quickhull with general precision for arbitrary dimension

Tags: c++, algorithm, convex-hull, convex

Is there any **C++** (**Java**, or similar easy translatable to **C++**) implementation of n-dimension quickhull algorithm for general precision numbers?

I am aware of the existence of the [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) implementation (is arbitrary dimension, is **C/C++**, but not general precision).

Comment: http://www.cgal.org/ probably this library is for you, but I'm not really into this stuff so I can't give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the Quickhull algorithm: https://github.com/tomilov/quickhull